# Matlab parfor loop works and then gives up half way through

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, regression, parfor

I'm using Matlab R2016a to do some regressions.

I have four 3-d matrices. The first three matrices represent "predictor" variables and the fourth matrix is the "response" variable, with data in the 3rd dimension representing samples at different times in the same location.

I want to regress all columns at the same x,y coordinate in the four matrices and get a single new 2044x1572 matrix of just the regression coefficients.

```
parfor A=1:2044
for B=1:1572

ZZ=squeeze(ARRAY_DETREND_L2_LST(A,B,:));
XX=squeeze(ARRAY_DETREND_L2_ONDVI(A,B,:));
YY=squeeze(ARRAY_DETREND_WB_85(A,B,:));
LL=squeeze(ARRAY_DETREND_L2_CNDVI(A,B,:));

end 

T=table([ZZ,XX,YY,LL,'VariableNames',{'LST','ONDVI','DROUGHT','NDVI'}]);

lm=fitlm(TABLE);
COEFF_LST(A,B)=lm.Coefficients.Estimate(2,1);

end
```

The code runs as is. However, the final layer that I want, which is a single 2044x1572 matrix of the regression coefficients is only half complete. The only warning I get is "Regression design matrix is rank deficient to within machine precision." However, I'm not worried about that. The data around my study area is NaN, so there are a lot of columns that are being regressed that are NaN.

If I change the code so that the two "end" statements are at the end, then I have the opposite problem of the code running perpetually.

[image]

It seems to me that this parfor code worked, but then parfor gave up in the middle. I had a version of this code working with just a for loop, but my data is impossibly large for a for loop to handle. The above image was created in a few minutes using parfor, which is something that would take many hours with a normal for loop.

Any feedback at all about what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand your code as currently written. You assign values to `ZZ`, `XX`, `YY` and `LL` in the inner loop but you don't use any of them, except for the values that come out of the last iteration. Then you create a table called `T` but don't use it; then you perform the linear regression fit on a variable called `TABLE` which is not assigned to anywhere, so it'll be the same on every loop iteration. I'm guessing `T` and `TABLE` should be the same variable, and all the code should be inside the inner loop (so yes, the two `end` statements should be at the end) but please can you check?

Comment: I'll have to recheck my code; I thought it would work (since it started to make the image I wanted) but apparently not. Thanks for your feedback.